# Allow new users to flag their own posts

Tags: feature-request, flags, new-users, spam

New users (<15 rep) cannot flag posts.

To test this, I created [another account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15883492/a-dumb-noob) and asked a question.

Sure enough, the `Flag` link was missing. But this makes new users vulnerable to spam or offense in a low-viewed question, and they can't do anything about it!

So can new users flag their own posts, just like they can always comment on their own posts?

I was thinking that *sometimes an evil user might go around asking questions and flagging every answer as "Spam" or "Offensive". Or they might treat the "In need of moderator attention" flag as a chat room.*

By doing something like this:

> flag: how are you doing?
>
> declined. not an actual issue.
>
> flag: hey, I'm doing good. How about you?
>
> declined: not an actual issue.

**For example**:
A user asks questions on a small site with not so many users. They immediately get an answer as follows:

> try [this product](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)! It will
> help you a lot, and it will definitely solve the problem that
> you are having.

<sub>this is a small site, so almost nobody notices</sub>

However, the user knows that this is spam, but they cannot flag it.

So my idea is to allow low rep users to flag their own posts, but then retract that ability after a few declined flags.

Comment: Why would someone need to flag a question they asked? I understand that someone might need to flag a comment (which they can) or an answer (I think they can flag answers to their own questions but I'm not 100%) but spam and offensive content in the question itself? Not sure about the need there.

Comment: *Why* would they flag their own post??

Comment: @Catija if a user discovers a spam account with no posts, common convention is to flag one of their own posts as "in need of moderator attention" and explain what happened.

Comment: I don't see how that lack of privilege makes new users questions prone to spam answers. We already run bots to detect spam, and also other community members will usually quickly flag and delete that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9SMQ.png is an example of spam that leaked through the filters

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask here. Please edit your question to clarify... It would be better if you could specify a scenario where a low rep user could be 'spammed' by other users and how the existing spam detecting infrastructure would fail at detecting it. *Or they might treat the "In need of moderator attention" flag as a chat room.* - I don't understand what you are asking here... Please elaborate...

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE While that question did get through SpamRam, it was detected and [reported by SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=58358739#58358739) about 1.5 minutes after it was posted and was deleted as spam almost exactly 1 minute later ([MS record](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/312173)).

Comment: Note: while you're specifically requesting flagging on posts, new users can already flag *comments* anywhere they can post a comment (i.e. they can flag comments on their own questions and answers, and comments on answers to their questions) See: [Allow new users to flag comments on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311459/271271)

Comment: [1-rep users can flag their own posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPnYb.png).

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I get where you're coming from now:

- Low-rep user has problem with spam or otherwise undesirable content in comments or in an answer.
- Low-rep user cannot flag as per the conventional workflow to have issue dealt with.
- Low-rep user is in a tag or in a portion of the site that is low-visibility or low-traffic.

The first thing would be to **demonstrate that this is a problem**.  Sure, I never venture much into [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), but that doesn't mean that *no one* does.  So someone would pick up on something there.

Second, given that every account starts at 1 rep and flags do go into a work queue, limiting the number of people who can start doing that is not a bad idea (think [2,769,502 users who are at least 15 rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1427923/1754500/) versus 12,219,262 users are have 14 rep or less).  Given the discrepancies in user count and scale, having ***6 times more flag traffic*** doesn't quite seem like a good idea.

Third, some of the mod tooling and other tooling (like SmokeDetector) do a reasonable job of covering the other spots; mods get notified if an answer is repeatedly posted around the site, and SmokeDetector reads just about everything flowing through the network and can notify if something *seems* to be off.

Don't see the value in this one.

Answer (score 5):

> A user asks questions in a small site with not so many users. They
> immediately get a comment as follows:
>
> > try [this product](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)! It will
> > help you a lot, and it will definitely solve the problem that
> > you are having.

Ok, so what you are asking is that low rep users can be exploited with spam comments like these in some less frequented tags. Hmm... this sounds like a valid concern, currently, [Smoke Detector](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/5072/smokedetector) (SD) doesn't detect comment spam and because this comment was made in a less frequented tag; it is unlikely that other higher-rep uses will notice it quick enough.

Makes sense... *but* the thing is that comment spam is rather rare. You need *some* rep to write comments and *usually* spammers aren't willing to work for that. Post (Q&A) spam on the other hand is far more prevalent -- Exactly why SD only focuses on posts...

Now if you *do* give < 15 rep uses flagging privileges then you open yourself up to a *lot* of flags from very inexperienced uses who; in the best-case scenario; are misflagging or; in the worst-case scenario; are actively trying to cause trouble.

So, this isn't a good idea.

---

I noticed that you changed the question to *"[...] immediately get an **answer** as follows"*.

If they receive an *answer* instead then the story is different. SD **can** detect spam answers using a variety of methods ranging from direct regex checks to checking if the Name Server Record is suspicious or not. It is pretty good at catching spam and if the bad actors in question keep using the same links then there is no way they can escape it.